# Как в allure выборочно передавать данные из теста java при его прогоне?

Tags: java, allure, cucumber

При прогоне теста `java+cucumber` формируется отчёт. Но отчёт содержит только шаги из `gerkin.feature`. В качестве логера использую `Slf4j`. Требуется отдельные параметры прогона теста, возникающие в рантайме, логировать в `allure`.

Comment: Какие параметры хотите видеть в отчёте?

Comment: @nikoshi , например значение id из `JSON response`. Т.е. в рамках теста я отправляю `JSON` запрос и получаю `JSON` ответ, в котором содержится сгенерированный `id`. Вот его и хочу отобразить в `allure` отчёте.

Comment: Хотите добавить в отчёт эти данные в виде файла?

Comment: нет, достаточно, чтобы в отчёте просто отобразился id, это ключевой парметр по которому, если что-то пошло не так, я буду смотреть логи.

Comment: Самый простой вариант - достать id из ответа и добавить в `message` при `AssertionError`, так вы увидите id в отчёте.

Comment: Можно создать слушатель и аттачить файл с логами при падении тестов

Comment: Спасибо, по второму способу можно чуть подробнее, пожалуйста - у меня мало опыта. Что значить аттачить и что за слушатель?

Comment: Создать слушатель, реализовав интерфейс `StepLifecycleListener` или `TestLifecycleListener` который будет прикреплять (аттачить) файл с логами или  файлы с телом реквеста/респонса, скриншоты и т. д. к отчёту. Нужно искать примеры и смотреть документацию. Возможно позже опишу пример

Comment: Спасибо, пойду искать!

Comment: Слушатель здесь нужен, если требуется выполнять какие-то действия по наступлению определённых событий или на определённых фазах жизненного цикла теста. Добавление файлов, скриншотов и т. д. реализуется в методах интерфейса, который будете имплементировать. Можно сделать и проще - просто создайте метод, который например будет записывать тело респонса или отправлять файл с логами и пометьте аннотацией `@Attachment` и вызывайте его в тесте, где нужно. Если вам нужно это, то я опишу пример в ответе

Comment: Да, это как раз то, что нужно. Буду благодарен за описание.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128653/discussion-between---and-nikoshi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь простые примеры добавления информации в отчёт (это далеко не все способы):

**Первый способ**: аннотация `@Attachment` см. [здесь](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.qameta.allure/allure-java-commons/latest/io/qameta/allure/Attachment.html) и [здесь](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_attachments)

Пометить этой аннотацией любой метод, который должен возвращать `String` или `byte[]`. Использовать аннотированный метод в любом месте в шаге теста/тесте.

Добавить текст:

```
@Attachment(value = "Заголовок вложения", type = "text/html")
public String sendMessageToReport(String message) {
    return message;
}
```

Использовать в шаге теста:

```
@Step
public void doSomething() {
    String id = getSomeId(); // получите ваш id и передайте в метод
    sendMessageToReport(id)
    // id будет в отчёте в разделе Test body > Step  ​
}
```

Добавить любой файл (документ, изображение, видео и пр.)

```
@Attachment
public static byte[] sendBytes(String resourceName) throws IOException {
    return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/main/resources", resourceName));
}
```

Использовать в шаге теста:

```
@Step
public void doSomething() {
    // передайте в метод имя документа, изображения, видео и пр.
    sendBytes("имя_файла")
    // файл будет в отчёте в разделе Test body > Step  ​
}
```

Аннотация `@Attachment` имеет 3 параматра: value/name — наименование вложения; type — тип информации в соответствии со стандартом MIME; fileExtension — опциональное расширение файла вложения, начинающееся с точки.

**Второй способ**: статический метод `addAttachment` из класса `Allure` см. [здесь](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.qameta.allure/allure-java-commons/latest/io/qameta/allure/Allure.html) и [здесь](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_attachments).
Метод перегружен и принимает до 4 аргументов: 2 обязательны (заголовок вложения и прикладываемый контент в виде `String` или `InputStream` из нужного файла), 2 опциональны (расширение файла и MIME-тип).

Добавить текст:

```
@Step()
public void doSomething() {
    String id = getSomeId(); // получите ваш id и передайте в метод
    Allure.addAttachment("Заголовок вложения", id);
    // id будет в отчёте в разделе Test body > Step
}
```

Повторюсь, что это далеко не все способы добавления информации в отчёт. Поищите примеры в сети. Также замечу, что удобнее применять слушатели `Allure` или используемых тестовых фреймворков, чтобы добавлять информацию в отчёт по наступлению событий: тест не прошёл/прошёл, тест начат/закончен, тест пропущен и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

В результате подключил плагин: `allure-maven` и использовал в коде `Allure.addAttachment("ID", "my id")`.